# How to update p:dataTable after completed upload in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm working with a web application with prime faces 6.1

I've a **p:fileUpload** with the option multiple="true" that I use to upload some images. 
When the last upload is completed, I use the **p:remoteCommand** in order to update a table that contains all the images just uploaded.

Inside this table I've some fields, and all goes fine except for the boolean fields. They are always false even if in the related controller are always true.

Here some minimal code

important sections of the xhtml page

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{provaController.handleFileUploadOnAddAdvertising}"
                          widgetVar="advImageUploaderVar"
                          auto="true"
                          mode="advanced" 
                          multiple="true"
                          allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jpe?g)$/"
                          oncomplete="handleMultiFileUploadRequest(PF('advImageUploaderVar'), afterAllUploadsCompleted);"

            />
            <p:remoteCommand name="afterAllUploadsCompleted" update="dataTableUploadedImages" />
            <p:dataTable id="dataTableUploadedImages" var="car" value="#{provaController.uploadedImagesOnAddAdvertisingAsList}">                                               
                <p:column headerText="booleanField" width="180">
                    <div align="center">
                        <p:selectBooleanButton value="#{car.booleanField}" onLabel="Yes" offLabel="No" />
                    </div>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="booleanObjectField" width="180">
                    <div align="center">
                        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{car.booleanObjectField}" />
                    </div>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="booleanAsStringField" width="180">
                    <div align="center">
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{car.booleanObjectField}" />
                    </div>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Date" width="180">
                    <div align="center">
                        <p:calendar value="#{car.dateField}" />
                    </div>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Integer" width="180">
                    <div align="center">
                        <p:inputNumber value="#{car.integerField}" />
                    </div>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="String" width="180">
                    <div align="center">
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.stringField}" />
                    </div>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="#{msg['anteprima']}">
                    <div align="center">
                        <p:graphicImage value="#{provaController.imagesForAddEditAdvertising}" width="200">
                            <f:param name="imageId" value="#{car.stringField}" />
                            <f:param name="cvlTimeStamp" value="#{now}" />
                        </p:graphicImage>
                    </div>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="#{msg['azioni']}" width="70">
                    <div align="center">
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="#{msg['cancella']}" action="#{provaController.removeUploadedImageOnAddAdvertising(car.stringField)}" update="dataTableUploadedImages" />
                    </div>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

Important parts of the controller

```
List<ProvaBean> uploadedImagesOnAddAdvertisingAsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<String, ProvaBean> uploadedImagesOnAddAdvertising = new HashMap<>();

    public void handleFileUploadOnAddAdvertising(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {

        ProvaBean pb = new ProvaBean();

        pb.setBooleanField(true);
        pb.setBooleanObjectField(Boolean.TRUE);
        pb.setBooleanAsStringField("true");
        pb.setDateField(new Date());
        pb.setIntegerField(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt());
        pb.setStringField(randomAlphanumeric(10));
        pb.setByteArrayField(event.getFile().getContents());

        uploadedImagesOnAddAdvertisingAsList.add(pb);
        uploadedImagesOnAddAdvertising.put(pb.getStringField(), pb);
    }

    public void removeUploadedImageOnAddAdvertising(String imageId) {
        ProvaBean a = uploadedImagesOnAddAdvertising.get(imageId);
        if (a != null) {
            uploadedImagesOnAddAdvertising.remove(imageId);
            uploadedImagesOnAddAdvertisingAsList.remove(a);
        }
    }

    public StreamedContent getImagesForAddEditAdvertising() {
        return getImagesForAddEditAdvertising(uploadedImagesOnAddAdvertising);
    }

    public StreamedContent getImagesForAddEditAdvertising(Map<String, ProvaBean> uploadedImagesOnAddAdvertising) {
        StreamedContent res;

        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
            res = manageRenderResponse();
        } else {
            String imageId = retrieveImageIdFromContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
            ProvaBean image = uploadedImagesOnAddAdvertising.get(imageId);
            if (image != null) {
                res = new ByteArrayContent(image.getByteArrayField(), "image/jpg", image.getStringField(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            } else {
                res = manageRenderResponse();
            }
        }

        return res;
    }

    private StreamedContent manageRenderResponse() {
        final Instant instant = Instant.now();
        String s = String.valueOf(instant.getEpochSecond());
        String n = String.valueOf(instant.getNano());
        return new ByteArrayContent(new byte[0], "image/jpg", s + n, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    }

    private String retrieveImageIdFromContext(FacesContext context) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("imageId")).orElse("");
    }

    private String randomAlphanumeric(int length) {

        return ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(48, 123)
                .filter(i -> (i < 58) || (i > 64 && i < 91) || (i > 96))
                .limit(length)
                .collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, i) -> sb.append((char) i), StringBuilder::append).toString();

    }
```

ProvaBean is a simple pojo with the following fields

```
    private Integer integerField;
    private Boolean booleanObjectField;
    private boolean booleanField;
    private String booleanAsStringField;
    private Date dateField; 
    private String stringField;
    private byte[] byteArrayField;
```

In order to be clear I remind you to the very detailed [original question](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=52257) and to [my github repository](https://github.com/classicPintus/pfRemoteCommand) that contains the basics in order to reproduce the problem.

Just download the repository and start it in TomEE or Glassfish.
After this, upload an image, and in the bottom table you'll see all the boolean fields value to false even if the controller sets that fields to true.

Why? Am I doing something wrong? Can you help me?

Comment: Code should be in [mcve] format IN the question...

Comment: Ok. Was only to avoid to have too much code. I'll do it

Comment: Thanks... In 99% of the cases, if you have too much code, it is not 'minimal'... but make sure it is also complete and verifyable

Comment: Please let me know if it's enough. I've tried to cut all the useless parts

Comment: Please read [mcve] again and also http://www.stackoverflow.com. It is neither minimal, nor complete and as it stands not verifyable. Try for yourself. Post the code as is in an empty project...

Comment: And is it actually upload related? Tried reproducimg without it?

Comment: No. I've just tried and the problem is the same also starting from a p:commandButton and maintain the same "on complete" shown in my example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153065/discussion-between-gavi-and-kukeltje).